# Can i get geocoding information from Google Geocoding API passing only the city?

Tags: geolocation, google-api, geocoding

I just need to fetch some geo data for a given *city*, i'm not interested (and i don't know) the address. Sending a request like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=fake,%20USA&sensor=false
```

will match a street with whe word *fake* in it, somewhere in USA. **How can i match only cities and get `ZERO_RESULTS` response if there is no city with that name?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with the Geocoding API unfortunately, from the [docs page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739)

The API will always look for a specific address and if it can't find an exact match from the string you provide it will always make a 'best effort' guess as to what you meant to try and find one. Only if it can't make this reasonable guess wil it return `ZERO_RESULTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I also just explore the API.how about using link like below

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:fake|country:US](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality%3afake%7Ccountry%3aUS)

locality equal to City and stated the country as US.It will return zero result.But if using this

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:fake|country:Nigeria](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality%3afake%7Ccountry%3aNigeria)

This will return the result.